# How to convert data frame with dictionary columns into multi level data frame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

I have DataFrame which contains dictionaries in the columns.

Can be created as below

```
 lis = [
     {'id': '1', 
     'author': {'self': 'A', 
     'displayName': 'A'}, 
     'created': '2018-12-18', 
     'items': {'field': 'status', 
         'fromString': 'Backlog'}}, 
     {'id': '2', 
     'author': {'self': 'B', 
     'displayName': 'B'}, 
     'created': '2018-12-18', 
     'items': {'field': 'status', 
         'fromString': 'Funnel'}}] 

pd.DataFrame(lis)  

                              author     created id                                           items
0  {'self': 'A', 'displayName': 'A'}  2018-12-18  1  {'field': 'status', 'fromString': 'Backlog'}
1  {'self': 'B', 'displayName': 'B'}  2018-12-18  2   {'field': 'status', 'fromString': 'Funnel'}
```

I want to convert this info multi level DataFrame.

I have been trying with

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product(lis) 
pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(pd.DataFrame(lis))
```

But not able to get the result i am looking for.Basically i want like below:

```
        author               created        id       items

self       displayName                             field   fromString
 A             A            2018-12-18       1      status   Backlog
 B             B            2018-12-18       2      status   Funnel
```

Any suggestions on how i can achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) - but columns names are flattened with `.` separator:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

lis = [
     {'id': '1', 
     'author': {'self': 'A', 
     'displayName': 'A'}, 
     'created': '2018-12-18', 
     'items': {'field': 'status', 
         'fromString': 'Backlog'}}, 
     {'id': '2', 
     'author': {'self': 'B', 
     'displayName': 'B'}, 
     'created': '2018-12-18', 
     'items': {'field': 'status', 
         'fromString': 'Funnel'}}] 

df = json_normalize(lis)
print (df)
  id     created author.self author.displayName items.field items.fromString
0  1  2018-12-18           A                  A      status          Backlog
1  2  2018-12-18           B                  B      status           Funnel
```

For `MulitIndex` in columns and in index - first create `Mulitiindex` by all columns without `.` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['id','created'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
print (df)
              author               items           
                self displayName   field fromString
id created                                         
1  2018-12-18      A           A  status    Backlog
2  2018-12-18      B           B  status     Funnel
```

If need `MulitIndex` in columns - it is possible, but get missing values in columns names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
print (df)
   id     created author               items           
  NaN         NaN   self displayName   field fromString
0   1  2018-12-18      A           A  status    Backlog
1   2  2018-12-18      B           B  status     Funnel
```

Missing values should be replaced by empty string:

```
df = df.rename(columns= lambda x: '' if x != x else x)
print (df)
  id     created author               items           
                   self displayName   field fromString
0  1  2018-12-18      A           A  status    Backlog
1  2  2018-12-18      B           B  status     Funnel
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, appreciate the step by step information

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, Hope this would help.

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(lis)
print(sorted(df.columns))

tupleList = [tuple(values.split(".")) if "." in values else (values,None) for values in sorted(df.columns)]

df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuplelist)
print(df)
```

Ouput will be as given below

```
author              created     id   items
displayName self    NaN         NaN  field  fromString
    A       A        2018-12-18  1   status  Backlog
    B       B        2018-12-18  2   status  Funnel
```